# How to capture values from JSON parent and sub-parent parameter using JQ?

Tags: json, jq

I have this below JSON file which I need to capture using JQ, but so far I only manage to capture the parent parameter (SUBSCRIBER_ID), but unable to capture the sub-parent parameter which is "Offer".

Need your guys help on providing a correct JQ filter to capture both "SUBSCRIBER_ID" and "Offer" value.

## JSON

```
{"Data1": [
   {"Data2": {
          "SUBSCRIBER_ID" : "999050280010099",
          "MSISDN" : "999050280010099",
          "EMAIL" : "john@email.com",
          "OFFERS" : [
                  {
                       "Offer" : 12344,
                       "EffectiveDate" : "1488787236",
                       "ExpiryDate" : "4070869200"
                  }               ],
          "IsGroup" : "false",
     }}
]}
```

---

## My JQ Filter which is not working

```
'.Data1 | .[] | .Data2 | to_entries |  map(.value) | @csv' -r
```

## Expected output:

```
SUBSCRIBER_ID,Offer
999050280010099,12344
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this `jq`:

```
jq -r '.Data1|.[]|.Data2|[.SUBSCRIBER_ID, .OFFERS[].Offer]|@csv' file > out.csv
```

(OR) As suggested by @peak,

```
jq -r '.Data1[].Data2|[.SUBSCRIBER_ID, .OFFERS[].Offer]|@csv' file
```

Another one method:

```
jq -r '.[]|.[]|map([.SUBSCRIBER_ID, .OFFERS[].Offer])|.[]|@csv' file
```

**Input:**

```
$ cat file.json
{
  "Data1": [
    {
      "Data2": {
        "SUBSCRIBER_ID": "999050280010099",
        "MSISDN": "999050280010099",
        "EMAIL": "john@email.com",
        "OFFERS": [
          {
            "Offer": 12344,
            "EffectiveDate": "1488787236",
            "ExpiryDate": "4070869200"
          }
        ],
        "IsGroup": "false"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Test:**

```
$ jq -r '.Data1|.[]|.Data2|[.SUBSCRIBER_ID, .OFFERS[].Offer]|@csv' file.json
"999050280010099",12344

$ jq -r '.[]|.[]|map([.SUBSCRIBER_ID, .OFFERS[].Offer])|.[]|@csv' file.json
"999050280010099",12344
```

Comment: Note that `.Data1|.[]|.Data2` can be shortened to: `.Data1[].Data2`, which may be easier on the eyes.

Comment: @peak, Good one. Updated.

Comment: @Maisa, Glad it worked for you. If this answer helped to solve your problem consider accepting it by clicking the tick mark on right side of an answer.